# Understanding how dnat works in iptables

Tags: linux, networking, firewall, iptables

I'm running 3 virtual machines with Fedora 19. The machine B is set up with two networks adapters and provides que channel between machine A and machine C.

The machine A IP is set to `192.168.1.3` and machine C IP is set to `172.16.1.1`. On machine B I have one adapter with IP `192.168.1.254` and another adapter with IP `172.16.1.254`.

I have to create a rule on machine B in the **NAT** table that allows an SSH connection to machine A but using the IP external address of machine B.

I've created this rule (don't know if this is correct or not):

> iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i p8p1 -s 172.16.1.1 -d 172.16.1.254 -p tcp --dport 22 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.3

If I only do this, if I use `netcat` I can't connect to machine A.
Now, if i insert this rule:

> iptables -A FORWARD -i p8p1 -o p7p1 -s 172.16.1.1 -d 192.168.1.3 -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

I can make the connection.

My question is this:

**Inserting the second rule doesn't make the first rule unnecessary?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first rule tells the kernel to nat packets coming from 172.16.1.1 for 172.16.1.254 on port 22 to 192.168.1.3.

The second rules tells it to allow packets coming from 172.16.1.1 going to 192.168.1.3 on port 22. This rule is applied after the first has nated the packet, so both are necessary if your default policy is to reject forwarded packets.

ASCII art diagram describing the process:

```
                      Packet (src -> dst)

          +-----------------------+--------------------+
machine C |            172.16.1.1 -> 172.16.1.254      |
          +-----------------------+--------------------+
                                  |
                                  v
          +---------------------p8p1-------------------+
          |                       |                    |
          |PREROUTING: 172.16.1.1 -> 192.168.1.3 (DNAT)|
machine B |                       |                    |
          |FORWARD:            ACCEPT                  |
          |                       |                    |
          +---------------------p7p1-------------------+
                                  v
                                  |
          +-----------------------+--------------------+
machine A |           172.16.1.1 -> 192.168.1.3        |
          +--------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Yes. My default policy is to reject packets. Many thanks for your explanation